# Ubuntu 16 IPSEC/L2TP "no acceptable traffic selectors found"

Tags: networking, 16.04, network-manager, vpn

I have successfully installed network-manager-l2tp for Ubuntu 16.04 using this guide: https://askubuntu.com/a/797764/578622

I can enter in all information needed and then enable the connection, but after a while it just says "connection failed".

I looked at `/var/log/syslog` and found the following:

```
Aug  6 16:43:21 pi-laptop NetworkManager[908]: initiating Main Mode IKE_SA nm-ipsec-l2tp-10981[1] to 193.170.109.20
Aug  6 16:43:21 pi-laptop NetworkManager[908]: generating ID_PROT request 0 [ SA V V V V ]
Aug  6 16:43:21 pi-laptop NetworkManager[908]: sending packet: from 192.168.0.11[500] to 193.170.109.20[500] (280 bytes)
Aug  6 16:43:21 pi-laptop NetworkManager[908]: received packet: from 193.170.109.20[500] to 192.168.0.11[500] (124 bytes)
Aug  6 16:43:21 pi-laptop NetworkManager[908]: parsed ID_PROT response 0 [ SA V V ]
Aug  6 16:43:21 pi-laptop NetworkManager[908]: received NAT-T (RFC 3947) vendor ID
Aug  6 16:43:21 pi-laptop NetworkManager[908]: received FRAGMENTATION vendor ID
Aug  6 16:43:21 pi-laptop NetworkManager[908]: generating ID_PROT request 0 [ KE No NAT-D NAT-D ]
Aug  6 16:43:21 pi-laptop NetworkManager[908]: sending packet: from 192.168.0.11[500] to 193.170.109.20[500] (244 bytes)
Aug  6 16:43:21 pi-laptop NetworkManager[908]: received packet: from 193.170.109.20[500] to 192.168.0.11[500] (304 bytes)
Aug  6 16:43:21 pi-laptop NetworkManager[908]: parsed ID_PROT response 0 [ KE No V V V V NAT-D NAT-D ]
Aug  6 16:43:21 pi-laptop NetworkManager[908]: received Cisco Unity vendor ID
Aug  6 16:43:21 pi-laptop NetworkManager[908]: received XAuth vendor ID
Aug  6 16:43:21 pi-laptop NetworkManager[908]: received unknown vendor ID: 00:99:c1:e5:06:c4:f7:b0:f0:62:e0:82:4f:8e:1a:aa
Aug  6 16:43:21 pi-laptop NetworkManager[908]: received unknown vendor ID: 1f:07:f7:0e:aa:65:14:d3:b0:fa:96:54:2a:50:01:00
Aug  6 16:43:21 pi-laptop NetworkManager[908]: local host is behind NAT, sending keep alives
Aug  6 16:43:21 pi-laptop NetworkManager[908]: generating ID_PROT request 0 [ ID HASH N(INITIAL_CONTACT) ]
Aug  6 16:43:21 pi-laptop NetworkManager[908]: sending packet: from 192.168.0.11[4500] to 193.170.109.20[4500] (100 bytes)
Aug  6 16:43:21 pi-laptop NetworkManager[908]: received packet: from 193.170.109.20[4500] to 192.168.0.11[4500] (84 bytes)
Aug  6 16:43:21 pi-laptop NetworkManager[908]: parsed ID_PROT response 0 [ ID HASH V ]
Aug  6 16:43:21 pi-laptop NetworkManager[908]: received DPD vendor ID
Aug  6 16:43:21 pi-laptop NetworkManager[908]: IKE_SA nm-ipsec-l2tp-10981[1] established between 192.168.0.11[192.168.0.11]...193.170.109.20[193.170.109.20]
Aug  6 16:43:21 pi-laptop NetworkManager[908]: scheduling reauthentication in 10080s
Aug  6 16:43:21 pi-laptop NetworkManager[908]: maximum IKE_SA lifetime 10620s
Aug  6 16:43:21 pi-laptop NetworkManager[908]: generating QUICK_MODE request 2613055945 [ HASH SA No ID ID NAT-OA NAT-OA ]
Aug  6 16:43:21 pi-laptop NetworkManager[908]: sending packet: from 192.168.0.11[4500] to 193.170.109.20[4500] (244 bytes)
Aug  6 16:43:21 pi-laptop NetworkManager[908]: received packet: from 193.170.109.20[4500] to 192.168.0.11[4500] (204 bytes)
Aug  6 16:43:21 pi-laptop NetworkManager[908]: parsed QUICK_MODE response 2613055945 [ HASH SA No ID ID N((24576)) NAT-OA NAT-OA ]
Aug  6 16:43:21 pi-laptop NetworkManager[908]: no acceptable traffic selectors found
Aug  6 16:43:21 pi-laptop NetworkManager[908]: establishing connection 'nm-ipsec-l2tp-10981' failed
Aug  6 16:43:21 pi-laptop NetworkManager[908]: ** Message: strongSwan ready for action.
```

After that the log continues and displays some information about xl2tp trying to connect, which is interesting because the connection already failed at `no acceptable traffic selectors found`?

Google just brought up some people saying it's an error in the config file syntax, but I don't believe that's the issue here as all configs were created by the aforementioned network-manager plugin and the log doesn't complain about config errors.

On my Windows system the connection works just fine, although I have to put a radius address in the EAP settings (following the instructions given by the server admin). Could that be a problem? On Android for example it just works out of the box...

Can anyone please explain to me what's happening here and how to fix it? I really need this VPN connection to work under Ubuntu.