# L2TP/ IPSec vpn server on ubuntu 16.10

Tags: networking, xubuntu, vpn

Hi,
I need a L2TP/ IPSec vpn server running on ubuntu-16.10-server-amd64 bit machine. Can anybody suggest any VPN software options for me?

Thanks

Munim

Comment: Possible duplicate of [L2tp IPSEC PSK VPN client on (x)ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/789421/l2tp-ipsec-psk-vpn-client-on-xubuntu-16-04)

Comment: Not a duplicate, the question in previous comment asks how to connect as a client, this question instead talks on how to setup a server

Answer (score 0):

Try StrongSwan:

https://www.strongswan.org

On the link you can find [installation](https://wiki.strongswan.org/projects/strongswan/wiki/InstallationDocumentation) and [configuration](https://wiki.strongswan.org/projects/strongswan/wiki/UserDocumentation) instructions, and also many [examples](https://www.strongswan.org/testresults4.html).

Comment: Invalid. StrongSwan does not implement L2TP.