# Ubuntu 16.04: Can't estabilish VPN connection to Stonesoft VPN

Tags: networking, network-manager, vpn, openvpn

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS 64-bit
I'm trying to estabilish a VPN connection to a Stonesoft VPN
As far as I know stonesoft means a L2TP VPN
Since Ubuntu seems no more support L2TP, I followed this instructions in order to create VPN: [Xerus - missing L2TP plugin for Network-Manager?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/762355/xerus-missing-l2tp-plugin-for-network-manager/840306#840306)

Sadly I still can't estabilish connection. They gave me only

- IP address
- Username
- Password

In the syslog I see the following:

```
Nov 12 09:58:42 immediata NetworkManager[996]: <info>  [1510477122.7520] audit: op="connection-activate" uuid="a944d391-ad32-4386-abed-902943385e1f" name="AreaVastaVpn" pid=2853 uid=1000 result="success"
Nov 12 09:58:42 immediata NetworkManager[996]: <info>  [1510477122.8019] vpn-connection[0x1523200,a944d391-ad32-4386-abed-902943385e1f,"AreaVastaVpn",0]: Started the VPN service, PID 4275
Nov 12 09:58:42 immediata NetworkManager[996]: <info>  [1510477122.8207] vpn-connection[0x1523200,a944d391-ad32-4386-abed-902943385e1f,"AreaVastaVpn",0]: Saw the service appear; activating connection
Nov 12 09:58:43 immediata gnome-session[2594]: Gtk-Message: GtkDialog mapped without a transient parent. This is discouraged.
Nov 12 09:59:16 immediata NetworkManager[996]: <info>  [1510477156.8682] keyfile: update /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/AreaVastaVpn (a944d391-ad32-4386-abed-902943385e1f,"AreaVastaVpn")
Nov 12 09:59:16 immediata NetworkManager[996]: <info>  [1510477156.8735] vpn-connection[0x1523200,a944d391-ad32-4386-abed-902943385e1f,"AreaVastaVpn",0]: VPN connection: (ConnectInteractive) reply received
Nov 12 09:59:16 immediata NetworkManager[996]: nm-l2tp[4275] <info>  ipsec enable flag: yes
Nov 12 09:59:16 immediata NetworkManager[996]: ** Message: Check port 1701
Nov 12 09:59:16 immediata NetworkManager[996]: ** Message: Can't bind to port 1701
Nov 12 09:59:16 immediata NetworkManager[996]: nm-l2tp[4275] <warn>  L2TP port 1701 is busy, using ephemeral.
Nov 12 09:59:16 immediata NetworkManager[996]: nm-l2tp[4275] <info>  starting ipsec
Nov 12 09:59:16 immediata NetworkManager[996]: Stopping strongSwan IPsec...
Nov 12 09:59:16 immediata charon: 00[DMN] signal of type SIGINT received. Shutting down
Nov 12 09:59:16 immediata ipsec[4316]: Stopping strongSwan IPsec failed: starter is not running
Nov 12 09:59:19 immediata NetworkManager[996]: Starting strongSwan 5.3.5 IPsec [starter]...
Nov 12 09:59:19 immediata NetworkManager[996]: Loading config setup
Nov 12 09:59:19 immediata NetworkManager[996]: Loading conn 'a944d391-ad32-4386-abed-902943385e1f'
Nov 12 09:59:19 immediata NetworkManager[996]: found netkey IPsec stack
Nov 12 09:59:19 immediata charon: 00[DMN] Starting IKE charon daemon (strongSwan 5.3.5, Linux 4.4.0-98-generic, x86_64)
Nov 12 09:59:19 immediata kernel: [  543.237222] audit: type=1400 audit(1510477159.053:41): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/lib/ipsec/charon" name="/usr/local/lib/libxml2.so.2.9.1" pid=4345 comm="charon" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=0 ouid=0
Nov 12 09:59:19 immediata charon: 00[CFG] disabling load-tester plugin, not configured
Nov 12 09:59:19 immediata charon: 00[LIB] plugin 'load-tester': failed to load - load_tester_plugin_create returned NULL
Nov 12 09:59:19 immediata charon: 00[CFG] dnscert plugin is disabled
Nov 12 09:59:19 immediata charon: 00[CFG] ipseckey plugin is disabled
Nov 12 09:59:19 immediata charon: 00[CFG] attr-sql plugin: database URI not set
Nov 12 09:59:19 immediata charon: 00[CFG] loading ca certificates from '/etc/ipsec.d/cacerts'
Nov 12 09:59:19 immediata charon: 00[CFG] loading aa certificates from '/etc/ipsec.d/aacerts'
Nov 12 09:59:19 immediata charon: 00[CFG] loading ocsp signer certificates from '/etc/ipsec.d/ocspcerts'
Nov 12 09:59:19 immediata charon: 00[CFG] loading attribute certificates from '/etc/ipsec.d/acerts'
Nov 12 09:59:19 immediata charon: 00[CFG] loading crls from '/etc/ipsec.d/crls'
Nov 12 09:59:19 immediata charon: 00[CFG] loading secrets from '/etc/ipsec.secrets'
Nov 12 09:59:19 immediata charon: 00[CFG] loading secrets from '/etc/ipsec.d/nm-l2tp-ipsec-7a4acce7-0546-4531-a80f-5fc950241a95.secrets'
Nov 12 09:59:19 immediata charon: 00[CFG]   loaded IKE secret for %any
Nov 12 09:59:19 immediata charon: 00[CFG] loading secrets from '/etc/ipsec.d/nm-l2tp-ipsec-8fa9aa57-6f5a-42cf-adf7-b84da24e632c.secrets'
Nov 12 09:59:19 immediata charon: 00[CFG]   loaded IKE secret for XX.XXX.XX.XX
Nov 12 09:59:19 immediata charon: 00[CFG] loading secrets from '/etc/ipsec.d/nm-l2tp-ipsec-a944d391-ad32-4386-abed-902943385e1f.secrets'
Nov 12 09:59:19 immediata charon: 00[CFG]   loaded IKE secret for %any
Nov 12 09:59:19 immediata charon: 00[CFG] sql plugin: database URI not set
Nov 12 09:59:19 immediata charon: 00[CFG] opening triplet file /etc/ipsec.d/triplets.dat failed: No such file or directory
Nov 12 09:59:19 immediata charon: 00[CFG] eap-simaka-sql database URI missing
Nov 12 09:59:19 immediata charon: 00[CFG] loaded 0 RADIUS server configurations
Nov 12 09:59:19 immediata charon: 00[CFG] no threshold configured for systime-fix, disabled
Nov 12 09:59:19 immediata charon: 00[CFG] coupling file path unspecified
Nov 12 09:59:19 immediata charon: 00[LIB] loaded plugins: charon test-vectors unbound ldap pkcs11 aes rc2 sha1 sha2 md4 md5 rdrand random nonce x509 revocation constraints acert pubkey pkcs1 pkcs7 pkcs8 pkcs12 pgp dnskey sshkey dnscert ipseckey pem openssl gcrypt af-alg fips-prf gmp agent chapoly xcbc cmac hmac ctr ccm gcm ntru bliss curl soup mysql sqlite attr kernel-netlink resolve socket-default connmark farp stroke updown eap-identity eap-sim eap-sim-pcsc eap-aka eap-aka-3gpp2 eap-simaka-pseudonym eap-simaka-reauth eap-md5 eap-gtc eap-mschapv2 eap-dynamic eap-radius eap-tls eap-ttls eap-peap eap-tnc xauth-generic xauth-eap xauth-pam xauth-noauth tnc-tnccs tnccs-20 tnccs-11 tnccs-dynamic dhcp whitelist lookip error-notify certexpire led radattr addrblock unity
Nov 12 09:59:19 immediata charon: 00[LIB] dropped capabilities, running as uid 0, gid 0
Nov 12 09:59:19 immediata charon: 00[JOB] spawning 16 worker threads
Nov 12 09:59:19 immediata charon: 07[CFG] received stroke: add connection 'a944d391-ad32-4386-abed-902943385e1f'
Nov 12 09:59:19 immediata charon: 07[CFG] added configuration 'a944d391-ad32-4386-abed-902943385e1f'
Nov 12 09:59:20 immediata charon: 06[CFG] rereading secrets
Nov 12 09:59:20 immediata charon: 06[CFG] loading secrets from '/etc/ipsec.secrets'
Nov 12 09:59:20 immediata charon: 06[CFG] loading secrets from '/etc/ipsec.d/nm-l2tp-ipsec-7a4acce7-0546-4531-a80f-5fc950241a95.secrets'
Nov 12 09:59:20 immediata charon: 06[CFG]   loaded IKE secret for %any
Nov 12 09:59:20 immediata charon: 06[CFG] loading secrets from '/etc/ipsec.d/nm-l2tp-ipsec-8fa9aa57-6f5a-42cf-adf7-b84da24e632c.secrets'
Nov 12 09:59:20 immediata charon: 06[CFG]   loaded IKE secret for XX.XXX.XX.XX
Nov 12 09:59:20 immediata charon: 06[CFG] loading secrets from '/etc/ipsec.d/nm-l2tp-ipsec-a944d391-ad32-4386-abed-902943385e1f.secrets'
Nov 12 09:59:20 immediata charon: 06[CFG]   loaded IKE secret for %any
Nov 12 09:59:20 immediata NetworkManager[996]: nm-l2tp[4275] <info>  Spawned ipsec up script with PID 4370.
Nov 12 09:59:20 immediata charon: 10[CFG] received stroke: initiate 'a944d391-ad32-4386-abed-902943385e1f'
Nov 12 09:59:20 immediata charon: 11[IKE] initiating Main Mode IKE_SA a944d391-ad32-4386-abed-902943385e1f[1] to XX.XXX.XX.XX
Nov 12 09:59:20 immediata charon: 11[ENC] generating ID_PROT request 0 [ SA V V V V ]
Nov 12 09:59:20 immediata charon: 11[NET] sending packet: from XX.XXX.XX.XX[500] to XX.XXX.XX.XX[500] (248 bytes)
Nov 12 09:59:20 immediata charon: 12[NET] received packet: from XX.XXX.XX.XX[500] to XX.XXX.XX.XX[500] (102 bytes)
Nov 12 09:59:20 immediata charon: 12[ENC] parsed INFORMATIONAL_V1 request 1567910028 [ N(NO_PROP) ]
Nov 12 09:59:20 immediata charon: 12[IKE] received NO_PROPOSAL_CHOSEN error notify
Nov 12 09:59:20 immediata NetworkManager[996]: initiating Main Mode IKE_SA a944d391-ad32-4386-abed-902943385e1f[1] to XX.XXX.XX.XX
Nov 12 09:59:20 immediata NetworkManager[996]: generating ID_PROT request 0 [ SA V V V V ]
Nov 12 09:59:20 immediata NetworkManager[996]: sending packet: from XX.XXX.XX.XX[500] to XX.XXX.XX.XX[500] (248 bytes)
Nov 12 09:59:20 immediata NetworkManager[996]: received packet: from XX.XXX.XX.XX[500] to XX.XXX.XX.XX[500] (102 bytes)
Nov 12 09:59:20 immediata NetworkManager[996]: parsed INFORMATIONAL_V1 request 1567910028 [ N(NO_PROP) ]
Nov 12 09:59:20 immediata NetworkManager[996]: received NO_PROPOSAL_CHOSEN error notify
Nov 12 09:59:20 immediata NetworkManager[996]: establishing connection 'a944d391-ad32-4386-abed-902943385e1f' failed
Nov 12 09:59:20 immediata NetworkManager[996]: Stopping strongSwan IPsec...
Nov 12 09:59:20 immediata charon: 00[DMN] signal of type SIGINT received. Shutting down
Nov 12 09:59:20 immediata NetworkManager[996]: nm-l2tp[4275] <warn>  Could not establish IPsec tunnel.
Nov 12 09:59:20 immediata NetworkManager[996]: (nm-l2tp-service:4275): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: g_dbus_method_invocation_take_error: assertion 'error != NULL' failed
Nov 12 09:59:20 immediata NetworkManager[996]: <info>  [1510477160.4101] vpn-connection[0x1523200,a944d391-ad32-4386-abed-902943385e1f,"AreaVastaVpn",0]: VPN service disappeared
Nov 12 09:59:20 immediata NetworkManager[996]: <warn>  [1510477160.4110] vpn-connection[0x1523200,a944d391-ad32-4386-abed-902943385e1f,"AreaVastaVpn",0]: VPN connection: failed to connect: 'Message recipient disconnected from message bus without replying'
```

Can anybody give me a tip on how I can solve the issue?
thank you
Angelo

**UPDATE**

Sorry I just saw in the log I posted the error related to the port 1701. I forgot to disable the xl2tpd service. I did it and I still can't connect

This is my new syslog trace

```
Nov 13 09:35:35 immediata NetworkManager[996]: <info>  [1510562135.1201] audit: op="connection-activate" uuid="a944d391-ad32-4386-abed-902943385e1f" name="AreaVastaVpn" pid=2853 uid=1000 result="success"
Nov 13 09:35:35 immediata NetworkManager[996]: <info>  [1510562135.1264] vpn-connection[0x15235c0,a944d391-ad32-4386-abed-902943385e1f,"AreaVastaVpn",0]: Started the VPN service, PID 8554
Nov 13 09:35:35 immediata NetworkManager[996]: <info>  [1510562135.1374] vpn-connection[0x15235c0,a944d391-ad32-4386-abed-902943385e1f,"AreaVastaVpn",0]: Saw the service appear; activating connection
Nov 13 09:35:35 immediata gnome-session[2594]: Gtk-Message: GtkDialog mapped without a transient parent. This is discouraged.
Nov 13 09:35:44 immediata NetworkManager[996]: <info>  [1510562144.2090] keyfile: update /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/AreaVastaVpn (a944d391-ad32-4386-abed-902943385e1f,"AreaVastaVpn")
Nov 13 09:35:44 immediata NetworkManager[996]: <info>  [1510562144.2150] vpn-connection[0x15235c0,a944d391-ad32-4386-abed-902943385e1f,"AreaVastaVpn",0]: VPN connection: (ConnectInteractive) reply received
Nov 13 09:35:44 immediata NetworkManager[996]: nm-l2tp[8554] <info>  ipsec enable flag: yes
Nov 13 09:35:44 immediata NetworkManager[996]: ** Message: Check port 1701
Nov 13 09:35:44 immediata NetworkManager[996]: nm-l2tp[8554] <info>  starting ipsec
Nov 13 09:35:44 immediata NetworkManager[996]: Stopping strongSwan IPsec failed: starter is not running
Nov 13 09:35:46 immediata NetworkManager[996]: Starting strongSwan 5.3.5 IPsec [starter]...
Nov 13 09:35:46 immediata NetworkManager[996]: Loading config setup
Nov 13 09:35:46 immediata NetworkManager[996]: Loading conn 'a944d391-ad32-4386-abed-902943385e1f'
Nov 13 09:35:46 immediata NetworkManager[996]: found netkey IPsec stack
Nov 13 09:35:46 immediata charon: 00[DMN] Starting IKE charon daemon (strongSwan 5.3.5, Linux 4.4.0-98-generic, x86_64)
Nov 13 09:35:46 immediata kernel: [ 2727.978478] audit: type=1400 audit(1510562146.258:46): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/lib/ipsec/charon" name="/usr/local/lib/libxml2.so.2.9.1" pid=8601 comm="charon" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=0 ouid=0
Nov 13 09:35:46 immediata charon: 00[CFG] disabling load-tester plugin, not configured
Nov 13 09:35:46 immediata charon: 00[LIB] plugin 'load-tester': failed to load - load_tester_plugin_create returned NULL
Nov 13 09:35:46 immediata charon: 00[CFG] dnscert plugin is disabled
Nov 13 09:35:46 immediata charon: 00[CFG] ipseckey plugin is disabled
Nov 13 09:35:46 immediata charon: 00[CFG] attr-sql plugin: database URI not set
Nov 13 09:35:46 immediata charon: 00[CFG] loading ca certificates from '/etc/ipsec.d/cacerts'
Nov 13 09:35:46 immediata charon: 00[CFG] loading aa certificates from '/etc/ipsec.d/aacerts'
Nov 13 09:35:46 immediata charon: 00[CFG] loading ocsp signer certificates from '/etc/ipsec.d/ocspcerts'
Nov 13 09:35:46 immediata charon: 00[CFG] loading attribute certificates from '/etc/ipsec.d/acerts'
Nov 13 09:35:46 immediata charon: 00[CFG] loading crls from '/etc/ipsec.d/crls'
Nov 13 09:35:46 immediata charon: 00[CFG] loading secrets from '/etc/ipsec.secrets'
Nov 13 09:35:46 immediata charon: 00[CFG] loading secrets from '/etc/ipsec.d/nm-l2tp-ipsec-7a4acce7-0546-4531-a80f-5fc950241a95.secrets'
Nov 13 09:35:46 immediata charon: 00[CFG]   loaded IKE secret for %any
Nov 13 09:35:46 immediata charon: 00[CFG] loading secrets from '/etc/ipsec.d/nm-l2tp-ipsec-8fa9aa57-6f5a-42cf-adf7-b84da24e632c.secrets'
Nov 13 09:35:46 immediata charon: 00[CFG]   loaded IKE secret for XX.XXX.XX.XX
Nov 13 09:35:46 immediata charon: 00[CFG] loading secrets from '/etc/ipsec.d/nm-l2tp-ipsec-a944d391-ad32-4386-abed-902943385e1f.secrets'
Nov 13 09:35:46 immediata charon: 00[CFG]   loaded IKE secret for %any
Nov 13 09:35:46 immediata charon: 00[CFG] sql plugin: database URI not set
Nov 13 09:35:46 immediata charon: 00[CFG] opening triplet file /etc/ipsec.d/triplets.dat failed: No such file or directory
Nov 13 09:35:46 immediata charon: 00[CFG] eap-simaka-sql database URI missing
Nov 13 09:35:46 immediata charon: 00[CFG] loaded 0 RADIUS server configurations
Nov 13 09:35:46 immediata charon: 00[CFG] no threshold configured for systime-fix, disabled
Nov 13 09:35:46 immediata charon: 00[CFG] coupling file path unspecified
Nov 13 09:35:46 immediata charon: 00[LIB] loaded plugins: charon test-vectors unbound ldap pkcs11 aes rc2 sha1 sha2 md4 md5 rdrand random nonce x509 revocation constraints acert pubkey pkcs1 pkcs7 pkcs8 pkcs12 pgp dnskey sshkey dnscert ipseckey pem openssl gcrypt af-alg fips-prf gmp agent chapoly xcbc cmac hmac ctr ccm gcm ntru bliss curl soup mysql sqlite attr kernel-netlink resolve socket-default connmark farp stroke updown eap-identity eap-sim eap-sim-pcsc eap-aka eap-aka-3gpp2 eap-simaka-pseudonym eap-simaka-reauth eap-md5 eap-gtc eap-mschapv2 eap-dynamic eap-radius eap-tls eap-ttls eap-peap eap-tnc xauth-generic xauth-eap xauth-pam xauth-noauth tnc-tnccs tnccs-20 tnccs-11 tnccs-dynamic dhcp whitelist lookip error-notify certexpire led radattr addrblock unity
Nov 13 09:35:46 immediata charon: 00[LIB] dropped capabilities, running as uid 0, gid 0
Nov 13 09:35:46 immediata charon: 00[JOB] spawning 16 worker threads
Nov 13 09:35:46 immediata charon: 09[CFG] received stroke: add connection 'a944d391-ad32-4386-abed-902943385e1f'
Nov 13 09:35:46 immediata charon: 09[CFG] added configuration 'a944d391-ad32-4386-abed-902943385e1f'
Nov 13 09:35:47 immediata charon: 05[CFG] rereading secrets
Nov 13 09:35:47 immediata charon: 05[CFG] loading secrets from '/etc/ipsec.secrets'
Nov 13 09:35:47 immediata charon: 05[CFG] loading secrets from '/etc/ipsec.d/nm-l2tp-ipsec-7a4acce7-0546-4531-a80f-5fc950241a95.secrets'
Nov 13 09:35:47 immediata charon: 05[CFG]   loaded IKE secret for %any
Nov 13 09:35:47 immediata charon: 05[CFG] loading secrets from '/etc/ipsec.d/nm-l2tp-ipsec-8fa9aa57-6f5a-42cf-adf7-b84da24e632c.secrets'
Nov 13 09:35:47 immediata charon: 05[CFG]   loaded IKE secret for XX.XXX.XX.XX
Nov 13 09:35:47 immediata charon: 05[CFG] loading secrets from '/etc/ipsec.d/nm-l2tp-ipsec-a944d391-ad32-4386-abed-902943385e1f.secrets'
Nov 13 09:35:47 immediata charon: 05[CFG]   loaded IKE secret for %any
Nov 13 09:35:47 immediata NetworkManager[996]: nm-l2tp[8554] <info>  Spawned ipsec up script with PID 8627.
Nov 13 09:35:47 immediata charon: 13[CFG] received stroke: initiate 'a944d391-ad32-4386-abed-902943385e1f'
Nov 13 09:35:47 immediata charon: 03[IKE] initiating Main Mode IKE_SA a944d391-ad32-4386-abed-902943385e1f[1] to XX.XXX.XX.XX
Nov 13 09:35:47 immediata charon: 03[ENC] generating ID_PROT request 0 [ SA V V V V ]
Nov 13 09:35:47 immediata charon: 03[NET] sending packet: from XX.XXX.XX.XX[500] to XX.XXX.XX.XX[500] (248 bytes)
Nov 13 09:35:51 immediata charon: 04[IKE] sending retransmit 1 of request message ID 0, seq 1
Nov 13 09:35:51 immediata charon: 04[NET] sending packet: from XX.XXX.XX.XX[500] to XX.XXX.XX.XX[500] (248 bytes)
Nov 13 09:35:57 immediata NetworkManager[996]: nm-l2tp[8554] <warn>  Timeout trying to establish IPsec connection
Nov 13 09:35:57 immediata NetworkManager[996]: nm-l2tp[8554] <info>  Terminating ipsec script with PID 8627.
Nov 13 09:35:57 immediata NetworkManager[996]: Stopping strongSwan IPsec...
Nov 13 09:35:57 immediata charon: 00[DMN] signal of type SIGINT received. Shutting down
Nov 13 09:35:57 immediata charon: 00[IKE] destroying IKE_SA in state CONNECTING without notification
Nov 13 09:35:57 immediata NetworkManager[996]: initiating Main Mode IKE_SA a944d391-ad32-4386-abed-902943385e1f[1] to XX.XXX.XX.XX
Nov 13 09:35:57 immediata NetworkManager[996]: generating ID_PROT request 0 [ SA V V V V ]
Nov 13 09:35:57 immediata NetworkManager[996]: sending packet: from XX.XXX.XX.XX[500] to XX.XXX.XX.XX[500] (248 bytes)
Nov 13 09:35:57 immediata NetworkManager[996]: sending retransmit 1 of request message ID 0, seq 1
Nov 13 09:35:57 immediata NetworkManager[996]: sending packet: from XX.XXX.XX.XX[500] to XX.XXX.XX.XX[500] (248 bytes)
Nov 13 09:35:57 immediata NetworkManager[996]: destroying IKE_SA in state CONNECTING without notification
Nov 13 09:35:57 immediata NetworkManager[996]: establishing connection 'a944d391-ad32-4386-abed-902943385e1f' failed
Nov 13 09:35:57 immediata NetworkManager[996]: nm-l2tp[8554] <warn>  Could not establish IPsec tunnel.
Nov 13 09:35:57 immediata NetworkManager[996]: (nm-l2tp-service:8554): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: g_dbus_method_invocation_take_error: assertion 'error != NULL' failed
Nov 13 09:35:57 immediata NetworkManager[996]: <info>  [1510562157.3575] vpn-connection[0x15235c0,a944d391-ad32-4386-abed-902943385e1f,"AreaVastaVpn",0]: VPN service disappeared
Nov 13 09:35:57 immediata NetworkManager[996]: <warn>  [1510562157.3587] vpn-connection[0x15235c0,a944d391-ad32-4386-abed-902943385e1f,"AreaVastaVpn",0]: VPN connection: failed to connect: 'Message recipient disconnected from message bus without replying'
Nov 13 09:36:06 immediata wpa_supplicant[1346]: wlan0: Failed to initiate sched scan
```

Can anybody give me a tip?

Thank you

Angelo

**UPDATE 2 ike-scan.sh RESULT**

I run the ike-scan.sh

Result of command `sudo ./ike-scan.sh XX.XXX.XX.XX | grep SA`

[ike-scan grep sa](https://pastebin.com/dC1vfLEH)

Result of command `sudo ./ike-scan.sh XX.XXX.XX.XX`

[ike-scan no grep](https://pastebin.com/9TFh9x1p)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to delete the following temp files that didn't get deleted for some reason :

```
sudo rm -f /etc/ipsec.d/nm-l2tp-ipsec-*.secrets
```

As mentioned on the following page :

- https://github.com/nm-l2tp/network-manager-l2tp/wiki/Prebuilt-Packages#ubuntu-1404-1604-and-1704

You can do the following to install network-manager-l2tp :

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nm-l2tp/network-manager-l2tp
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install network-manager-l2tp network-manager-l2tp-gnome
```

The 'Can't bind to port 1701' xl2tpd warning isn't an error, but it can be an issue for some firewall and/or VPN Servers when an ephemeral port is used, more details here:

- https://github.com/nm-l2tp/network-manager-l2tp#issue-with-not-stopping-system-xl2tpd-service

But I think the 'received NO_PROPOSAL_CHOSEN error' you have is because the VPN server is only proposing old broken encryption algorithms, see:

- https://github.com/nm-l2tp/network-manager-l2tp#vpn-servers-using-ipsec-ikev1-broken-algorithms

It provides details on how to query the VPN server for the algorithms it supports and provides an example for a common broken algorithm workaround. But the recommended fix is to reconfigure the VPN server to use stronger algorithms.

If you are still having issues and assuming you are using the above PPA repository, you could try replacing strongswan with libreswan by issuing :

```
sudo apt install libreswan
```

but be sure to remove any phase 1/phase 2 algorithms you might have entered in the IPsec Options dialog box as the version of libreswan in that PPA repository hasn't dropped the common broken algorithms from its default set of proposals.

Might also want to restart NetworkManager to ensure the libreswan change has been picked up by NetworkManager-l2tp :

```
sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager.service
```

Comment: Sadly what suggested didn't work

Comment: what is the output of running the ike-scan.sh script mentioned on the following page ?

https://github.com/nm-l2tp/network-manager-l2tp/wiki/Known-Issues#querying-vpn-server-for-its-supported-ipsec-ikev1-algorithms

Comment: I updated my question by providing command result; please see section UPDATE 2 ike-scan.sh RESULT

Comment: The ike-scan.sh output explains the original NO_PROPOSAL_CHOSEN error.

Comment: Are you sure the Stonesoft VPN has been configured for IPsec IKEv1? Perhaps it might have only been configured for IPSec IKEv2 which might explain the ike-scan.sh output.

L2TP/IPsec only uses IKEv1, with IPsec IKEv2, there is no need for L2TP and the network-manager-strongswan VPN client is the correct one to use.

Comment: I've been looking at http://help.stonesoft.com/onlinehelp/StoneGate/SMC/5.7.3/SGAG/SGOH_VPNs/Defining_IPsec_SA_Settings_for_a_VPN.htm  and have added the Message Digest Algorithms (aka hash algorithms) and Diffie-Hellman Groups that were mentioned there to an updated ike-scan.sh on https://github.com/nm-l2tp/network-manager-l2tp/wiki/Known-Issues#querying-vpn-server-for-its-supported-ipsec-ikev1-algorithms  but don't know if it'll find any proposals

Comment: Thank you for the support. Sadly also by using the network-manager-strongswan VPN client i couldn’t establish connection. The only solution I could adopt is to use a windows virtual machine

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned Ubuntu no longer seems to support L2TP. Ubuntu 17.10 (and later) come with network-manager-l2tp package by default in a standard repository.

As mentioned on the following PPA page:

- https://launchpad.net/~nm-l2tp/+archive/ubuntu/network-manager-l2tp

> If you would like these backported packages added to an official Ubuntu 16.10 or 17.04 backports repository, please login to the following page and click the "Does this bug affect you?" link to vote to have them added:
>
> https://bugs.launchpad.net/xenial-backports/+bug/1697934

Unfortunately only 6 Ubuntu users have voted to have the package backported officially to Ubuntu 16.04, so seems unlikely to happen.

Comment: Well sadly I can refer to my distribution and on what I saw in the net. Upgrade to Ubuntu 17.10 is not an option for me now

Comment: I wasn't trying to suggest upgrading to Ubuntu 17.10, just explaining why there is no official package for Ubuntu 16.04 as no one is voting for the backport of Ubuntu 17.10's network-manager-l2tp package to Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: OK; now I got it :)